# Multiplying each object on array PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to detect the last three digits of lines that look like this:

```
    19 33380 32826 13     50      2    600
    19 33393 32813 13     50      2    600
    65 33396 32816 13     50      4    600
    65 33376 32806 13     50      2    600
    65 33376 32829 13     50      3    600
    83 33381 32806 13     50      5    600
    100 33376 32822 13     50      2    600
    100 33399 32813 13     50      2    600
```

And multiply them by 3. I am using the following script to do so, but until now it isn't possible. It sends invalid operation.

```
    <?php

$rale = 0.4;

$list = @shell_exec("grep -R 'MonsterHomes' /game/dat");
if(!$list)
        exit;

foreach(explode("\n", $list) as $v) {
        $v = trim($v);
        $f = explode(":", $v);
        $f = $f[0];
        if(!($str = @file_get_contents($f)))
                continue;

preg_match_all('/.[0-9][0-9]$/m', $str, $rate);
foreach( $rate as &$val ){ $val *= 2; }
print_r ($val);
}
```

It just prints out the output for now, but I want it to put the contents on the file. Any idea of how why my error is happening? thanks in advance.

Comment: looks overcomplicated

Comment: There's no reason to use a bash script when you can do the same in php. As an aside why do you use the `-R` option with grep?